# hermitian matrix with beamforming vector in adaptive beamforming systems

Tags: matlab

I'm reading the paper of beamforming.
But, I don't know about the meaning of the w* w.
w is beamforming vector and * is conjugate transpose.

I found many related data of w* w but I found only E[ w* w ].
what is the meaning of w*w exactly?

And, I don't understand the meaning of beamforming vector.

Please let me know about those things.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question. w*.w is simply the length of the vector squared.